# Memory leaks in requests library

Tags: python, python-requests

I noticed a very large increase in memory usage when retrieving a pdf file using requests library. The file itself is ~4MB large but physical memory allocated to python processes increases by more than 150MB !

Is anyone aware of the possible causes (and maybe fixes) of such behavior?

This is the test case:

```
import requests,gc
def dump_mem():
  s = open("/proc/self/status").readlines()
  for line in s:
    if line.startswith("VmRSS"):
      return line
```

Below is the output I got in intrepretter.

```
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> dump_mem()
'VmRSS:\t   13772 kB\n'
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.ipd.uni-karlsruhe.de/~ovid/Seminare/DWSS05/Ausarbeitungen/Seminar-DWSS05')
>>> gc.collect()
5
>>> dump_mem()
'VmRSS:\t   20620 kB\n'
>>> r.headers['content-length']
'4089190'
>>> dump_mem()
'VmRSS:\t   20628 kB\n'
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> c = r.content
>>> dump_mem()
'VmRSS:\t   20628 kB\n'
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> t = r.text
>>> gc.collect()
8
>>> dump_mem()
'VmRSS:\t  182368 kB\n'
```

Obviously I shouldn't try to decode a pdf file as text. But what is the cause of such behavior anyway?

Comment: As you mention, it seems strange to read it as text. Did you try to use `read` instead of `readlines`, and `str.index` instead of `str.startswith`? If it doesn't exhibit the same behaviour, then this is not a problem on `requests`.

Comment: @goncalopp: the dump_mem function is only used to display memory usage, and is clearly not the cause of the memory increase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When no `charset` parameter is included in the content type and the response is *not* a `text/` mimetype, then a character detection library is used to determine the codec.

By using `response.text` you triggered this detection, loading the library, and it's modules include some sizable tables.

Depending on the exact version of `requests` you have installed, you'll find that `sys.modules['requests.packages.chardet']` or `sys.modules['requests.packages.charade']` is now present, together with around 36 of sub-modules, where it wasn't before you used `r.text`.

As the detection runs, a number of objects are created that use various statistical techniques on your PDF document, as detection fails to hit on any specific codec with enough certainty. To fit all this in memory, Python requests more memory to be allocated from your OS. Once the detection process is complete, that memory is freed again, but the OS does *not* then de-allocate that memory, not immediately. This is done to prevent wild memory churn as processes can easily request and free memory in cycles.

Note that you **also** added the result of `r.text` to your memory, bound to `t`. This is a Unicode text object, which in Python 2 takes up between 2 and 4 times as much memory as the bytestring object. The specific download you have there is nearly 4 MB as a bytestring, but if you are using a UCS-4 Python build, then the resulting Unicode value adds another 16MB *just for the decoded value*.

Comment: So is the spectacular memory increase due to the decoding tables in character detection libraries? If this would be true the same memory blow-up would happen when I do a `r.text` for simple html pages, isn't it?

Comment: @Eugen: The detectors are loaded on demand; by feeding in a large PDF file you simply temporarily ballooned the memory footprint. The OS doesn't immediately take all that memory back.

Comment: Also, the garbage collector isn't going to collect the content and text bindings that were created. I find it hard to believe chardet's tables are this large on their own. Keep in mind also that `r.content` is cached and so just doing `del c` won't be enough. Also if the pdf is large enough, `t` will not be gc'd.