# Memory leak from a docker container with a Flask application

Tags: python, flask

I am having a strange problem, when I start multiple docker containers with Flask applications. The containers with the apps are used for simulation purposes and are not deployed for production, I simply needed a way to allow the docker containers to communicate between each other and GET/POST API calls seemed to be a good solution. However, this is where my problem occurred, when I start the containers and the Flask application starts, the memory usage (which I am observing with `htop`) starts to increase. Just by starting the Flask server, the container size increases by 200 MB. I can honestly live with that, however, the problem is, that after every API call, the memory usage keeps increasing. Here is a small snippet of one of the functions:

```
@app.route('/execute/step=<int:step>', methods=['GET'])
def execute(step):
    url = f'http://my_url:5000/some/api/call/step={step}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = eval(response.text)

    if data:
        # unimportant calculations

        if demand <= supply:
            for b in people_b:
                buyer_id = b['id']
                post_data = {some_data}
                url = f'http://my_url:5000/set_data/id={buyer_id}'
                requests.post(url, data=post_data)

            for s in people_s[:-1]:

                seller_id = s['id']
                post_data = {some_data
                             }
                url = f'http://my_url:5000/set_data/id={seller_id}'
                requests.post(url, data=post_data)

            # unimportant steps

            seller_id = local_ids[-1]['id']
            post_data = {some_data}
            url = f'http://my_url:5000/set_data/id={seller_id}'
            requests.post(url, data=post_data)

            return 'Success\n'
        else:
            for s in people_s:
                seller_id = s['id']
                post_data = {some_data}
                url = f'http://my_url:5000/set_data/id={seller_id}'
                requests.post(url, data=post_data)

            for b in people_b[:-1]:
                #unimportant steps

                buyer_id = b['id']
                post_data = {some_data}
                url = f'http://my_url:5000/set_data/id={buyer_id}'
                requests.post(url, data=post_data)

            #unimportant steps

            buyer_id = people_b[-1]['id']
            post_data = {some_data}
            url = f'http://my_url:5000/set_data/id={buyer_id}'
            requests.post(url, data=post_data)

            return 'Success\n'
    else:
        return 'No success\n'
```

Above is one of the methods, I have deleted some unimportant computation steps, but what I wanted to show is, that there are nested API calls as well. I tried calling `gc.collect()` before every return in the functions, however, this resulted no success.

Is this behavior expected when performing so many API calls or is there a problem with the implementation or docker/Flask usage?

Comment: Looks like `response.text` might be the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656207/memory-leaks-in-requests-library

Comment: Try running with `response.content` (or some dummy content) and see if you get the same memory leaks?

Comment: `eval` is evil. Don't get used to it! Use JSON!

Comment: I am still not fully aware, what would the difference be if I use `response.json()` and `response.content`. Apparently using `response.text` and `eval()` is not optimal, but what about the other two?

Comment: Anyways, I removed `eval` and `response.text` and the memory leaks are gone. If someone posts an answer, I would happily accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the memory leak was entirely due to using `eval` and `response.text`. After switching to using `json` output, the memory leaks were gone.